# How to optimize code using binary, variable lookup and foreach?

Tags: arrays, performance, perl, lookup, calc

How can I optimize this Perl script?

It takes "days of the week" such as "Mon and "Tue" or "Wed, Thu and Sun" and simply returns an integer to represent them.

```
use strict;
use feature qw(signatures);
use warnings;
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);
my $DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP = ( { mon  =>  1, tue  =>  2, wed  =>  4, thu  =>  8, fri  => 16, sat  => 32, sun  => 64 });

my $days_of_week_integer= days_of_week_to_int (['zzz', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'fri', 'SAT']);
print "$days_of_week_integer\n";


sub days_of_week_to_int ($days) {
  my $day_of_week = 0;
  foreach my $key (@$days)  {
    $day_of_week += $DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP->{lc($key)} if $DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP->{lc($key)};
  }
  return $day_of_week if $day_of_week < 128;
  return;
}
```

I am always looking to understand how to optimize my code better and gain experience from seasoned developers. The script works perfectly well and well it's in Perl so it already runs very fast.

However, I can't help feeling there is a more optimum "Perl way" of achieving the same result and I wondered if anyone felt the same and could show me the way. Small tips are important tips!

Thank you to everybody and I add the final code here with the benchmarks. This is my original code with the extra overhead stripped but faithful to the original with the polar bear code.

```
use strict;
use Benchmark ':all';

my $polar_bitmap = 0x01;
my @polar_days_of_week = qw/Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun/;         # USA/Canada week days order
my $orig_DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP = ( { Mon  =>  1, Tue  =>  2, Wed  =>  4, Thu  =>  8, Fri  => 16, Sat  => 32, Sun  => 64 });
my %polar_DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP = map { $_ => ( $polar_bitmap <<= 1 ) / 2 } @polar_days_of_week;

my @days;
@days  = qw/Mon Wed Tue Sat Sun Thu/;

print "orig  : " . (orig_days_of_week_to_int(@days)) . "\n";
print "polar : " . (polar_days_to_mask    ( \@days)) . "\n";

@days = qw/Mon Sat Sun Thu/;

print "polar : " . (polar_days_to_mask(\@days)) . "\n";
print "orig  : " . (orig_days_of_week_to_int(@days)) . "\n";

@days = qw/Mon Wed Tue Sat Sun Thu/;

cmpthese(-3, {
    orginal  => sub { orig_days_of_week_to_int(@days) },
    polar_b  => sub { polar_days_to_mask(\@days)      },
});

exit 0;

sub polar_days_to_mask {
    my $days = shift;
    my $mask;

    $mask ^= $polar_DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP{$_} for @$days;

    return $mask;
}

sub orig_days_of_week_to_int  {
  my @days = @_;
  my $day_of_week = 0;
  foreach my $key (@days)  {
    $day_of_week += $orig_DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP->{$key};
  }
  return $day_of_week;
}
```

And the output:

```
orig  : 111
polar : 111
polar : 105
orig  : 105
             Rate orginal polar_b
orginal 1411082/s      --    -41%
polar_b 2398719/s     70%      --
```

I've added the code above just in case I messed anything up as you always should be careful with BenchMarks!  :-)

And to show that above point... I thought I would test it with a LINODE node that I have...

```
            Rate orginal polar_b
orginal 741061/s      --    -25%
polar_b 992490/s     34%      --
```

*Actually, compared to my HP bare-metal at home... the LINODE gives me say 34% consistently and my home machine 70%.  (same o/s, same versions)*

So there you are...be wary of Benchmarks!

Never the less, part man, part bear, part AI, the Polar solution was coool.

Comment: Why the hashref and arrayref instead of plain hash and list?

Comment: The returned value seems to be incorrect if a day is repeated in the input.

Comment: To answer you both (I am learning).  I thought a reference would be faster so I used that.  And choroba,, cannot have multiple days in a week which this "formula" (in where it's being used) expects... so yes, observation true and intended behaviour.

Comment: Could you please clarify the expected behavior? In particular, you seem happy with Polar Bear's solution, even though it used `^=` instead of `+=` and omits `lc`.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone and what a fine bunch of people you are. Perl is strong. I selected PolarBear as his solution was raw, base and I thought broke it down to the constitute components. And there was no library used... raw... a very pristine solution. And it was x2 200% faster than my original solution. I have learnt a lot from you guys.

Comment: @Dada, it is true that the Polar solution lacked error checking, lacked lc and also did not return an integer. It did not meet the intended behavior as per the question. But the Bear did answer what I was looking for even if I asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like OP attempts to generate bitmask for week days based on provided sample code.

Please investigate following code snippet which is provided for demonstration purpose only. Feel free to strip unneeded parts with demo output.

Note: the code utilizes USA/Canada day order, for Europe move `Sun` to the end of the list

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $bitmap = 0x01;
my @days_of_week = qw/Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat/;         # USA/Canada week days order
my %DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP = map { $_ => ( $bitmap <<= 1 ) / 2 } @days_of_week;

my @days = qw/Mon Wed Thu Sat/;

say '
 Result
---------------';
printf "Days: %s\n", join(',',@days);
printf "Mask: 0b%08b\n", days_to_mask(\@days);

exit 0;

sub days_to_mask {
    my $days = shift;
    my $mask;
    
    $mask ^= $DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP{$_} for @$days;
    
    return $mask;
}
```

Output

```
 Result
---------------
Days: Mon,Wed,Thu,Sat
Mask: 0b01011010
```

Reference: [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html), [ref ISO 8601](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days/), [Wiki ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Hi Polar, are you a robot? Actually in solution I wanted INTEGER but I can covert binary to INT and also check benchmark. I have not checked it yet but this "map" again looks fast.... overall I am looking to optimize this code as it is called billions of times in real use so I can check BM tomorrow, I have not done that yet. I am grateful for your response.

Comment: Perhaps you are the robot, I did output in binary format so that you could see what bits are turned on. Internally all numbers are represented in binary form -- you can do `print days_to_mask(\@days)`, `say days_to_mask(\@days)` to get integer form.

Comment: Just on side note `XOR` fastest operation in CPU (you just can not beat it in speed). Perhaps slowest part in code is getting days from an array.

Comment: Thank you... I got it. Your solution is the cleanest of all. 
I will BM tomorrow.  It is so simple, a building block, DNA. Love that.

Comment: Well, when you speak __binary__ many tasks look quite simple and fast. One good example is Arduino -- if use __standard__ interface functions to manipulate bits the program gets big and slow, but when you operate directly registers bits the program becomes very small, extremely fast and provides plenty available resources. All what is required -- spend a little bit time to read datasheet for MCU. Note: perhaps `XOR` and `SHIFT` can compete for first place in CPU execution speed.

Comment: What an amazing robot you are. Your solution does not feature error correction but without that it is x2 faster than my original after I've removed the error correction from the original. 

Your solution uses no libraries. 

And your solution essentially achieves the essence of what I wanted... how can I reduce this "already simple perl code" to it's base building blocks to achieve both performance and nature.

You map the hash but XOR the loop.

So we now know that PolarBear is not a robot, he is the modern day binary artificial intelligence system MK3.

I thank everybody.

Comment: Well `map` is a fancy `for` loop -- but looks nice in the code, eye pleaser. Glad that the solution does what it suppose do well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236116/discussion-between-mark-arnold-and-polar-bear).

Comment: What is the point of the references to ISO 8601? Is it meant to suggest OP to use standard day abbreviations to avoid requiring `lc`? If so, it would be clearer to explicitly state that. (and if not, I have no idea how ISO 8601 is relevant, and an explanation might be useful)

Comment: @Dada -- to point difference between USA/Canada and Europe first day of the week (USA/Canada do not follow ISO 8601 -- still using imperial system: pound, miles, gallons).

Comment: Any reason to use 'XOR',  `^`, instead of 'OR', `|`? When I run your code with 'OR', it produces the same mask.

Comment: @Chris Charley -- there is no particular reason, both operation in this case produce same result (initially `$mask` is undefined what is equal `0`). Both operations should take about same number of CPU cycles. `XOR` has some advantages in other cases like _zeroing registers_ and _flipping a bit_ but it is not applicable in this particular case.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't done any benchmarking, but I think this is cleaner (Notes in comments):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw/signatures/; # Instead of use feature and no warnings
use feature qw/say/;
use List::Util qw/sum0/;

# Plain hash instead of hashref
my %DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP = ( mon => 1, tue => 2, wed => 4, thu => 8,
                            fri => 16, sat => 32, sun => 64 );

# Function takes a list of values instead of a single arrayref
my $days_of_week_integer = days_of_week_to_int('zzz', 'Sun', 'Mon',
                                               'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'fri', 'SAT');

# say instead of "print "$foo\n"
say $days_of_week_integer;

sub days_of_week_to_int (@days) {
    no warnings qw/uninitialized/; # Turn off warning about undef values
    # Sum up the results of a hash slice instead of using an explicit loop
    my $day_of_week = sum0 @DAYS_OF_WEEK_LOOKUP{map { lc } @days};
    return $day_of_week < 128 ? $day_of_week : undef;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shawn. Your code has shown me a lot of simple things yet these simple things are the building blocks to make code an art not a job. I *did* do some benchmarks and I would agree that optimization should not get in the way of code readability except in exceptional circumstance.  You have achieved both.

Comment: Perl Benchmark gives a near 100% improvements. Rate  org  new
org  625570/s   -- -48%
new 1191563/s  90%   --

Answer (score 4):

There can be a small measure of speedup with tweaks: use a `map` instead of manual iteration and add numbers using a library, use a test that short-circuits and so is done rarely in this case instead of an `if` test every time. More importantly, that may be a bit more readable.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::Util qw(sum0);
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $runfor = shift // 3;

my $DAYS_OF_WEEK = { mon => 1, tue => 2, wed => 4, thu => 8, fri => 16, 
    sat => 32, sun => 64 };    

sub add_days_hr {
    my $days = shift;
    my $ndow = sum0 map { $DAYS_OF_WEEK->{lc($_)} // () } @$days;
    return $ndow < 128 ? $ndow : undef;
}

sub dow_to_int {  # original code (from question)
    my $days = shift;
    my $day_of_week = 0;
    foreach my $key (@$days)  {
        $day_of_week += $DAYS_OF_WEEK->{lc($key)} if $DAYS_OF_WEEK->{lc($key)};
    }   
    return $day_of_week if $day_of_week < 128;
    return;
}
    
my @test_days = qw(zzz Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu fri SAT);

cmpthese( -$runfor, { 
    add_days_hr => sub { add_days_hr( \@test_days ) },
    dow_to_int  => sub { dow_to_int ( \@test_days ) },
});
```

Prints, on an old laptop with 5.16

```
                Rate  dow_to_int add_days_hr
dow_to_int  526696/s          --        -12%
add_days_hr 599792/s         14%          --
```

This can be made a little faster yet by using a a hash instead of hashref to avoid dereferencing and by using flat input list (array instead of arrayref) which needn't be dereferenced, but that's already eating into the intended interface for small gains.

If this is done repeatedly it can be sped up more by inlining it, since sub calls are spendy in Perl.

---

On a server, with two more cases

```
                 Rate   add_other  dow_to_int add_days_hr    add_days
add_slice    900635/s          --         -5%        -17%        -21%
dow_to_int   952705/s          6%          --        -12%        -16%
add_days_hr 1079487/s         20%         13%          --         -5%
add_days    1133645/s         26%         19%          5%          --
```

Legend: `add_slice` is a solution using slice (from Shawn's), `dow_to_int` the original code (as above), `add_days_hr` the solution above, and `add_days` the same one but using a hash for the lookup (not hashref)

```
# These two need %DAYS_OF_WEEK hash
my %DAYS_OF_WEEK = ( mon => 1, tue => 2, wed => 4, thu => 8, fri => 16,
    sat => 32, sun => 64 );

sub add_slice {  # from Shawn's answer
    my $days = shift;
    no warnings qw/uninitialized/;
    my $day_of_week = sum0 @DAYS_OF_WEEK{map { lc } @$days};
    return $day_of_week < 128 ? $day_of_week : undef;
}

sub add_days {   # With hash lookup instead of hashref, otherwise same
    my $days = shift;
    my $ndow = sum map { $DAYS_OF_WEEK{lc($_)} // () } @$days;
    return $ndow < 128 ? $ndow : undef;
}
```

Comment: Well this is just brilliant as well. I will take a proper look tomorrow yet this really makes sense.

Comment: A 100% speed up with more code readability... the thing I have learnt here is that the "map" function does not feature anywhere in "my" code and clearly this is like doh! I think my code is good but not optimum.  I have learnt other stuff but this is my super takeaway. I will look tomorrow at solutions and close project off... chow.

Comment: @MarkArnold Yes, `map` can be very useful for readability and cleaner code.  (But I don't see anything near 100% speedup, and I don't see where you'd get that.)

Comment: Comparing my original with I think Shawn solution:

```         Rate  org  new
org  601510/s   -- -50%
new 1194348/s  99%   --```   I will post in main code block as I am new to stackoverflow!

Comment: @MarkArnold Perhaps worth saying: be very careful with benchmarking. It is tricky and it is easy to introduce subtle biases. Your posted code is solid -- there's a lookup and a basic loop -- well, that's all there is to it.  There is nothing serious to be done there and I don't think it's possible to half the execution time just so. (There's that `if` done every time but that's truly minute.)  Could your benchmark be skewed somehow?

Comment: @MarkArnold   [cont'd]   Even the bitmask solution, which is another game that _is_ faster (wasn't considered by me or Shawn probably because you asked to improve your sub) in my benchmark isn't (nearly) 100% better.  Just a warning to be careful with timings/benchmark :)

Comment: your warnings are well heard. This is yes an optimization question. I am now using the UTIL module elsewhere in my code because of other solutions. I have taken the time to remove the error checking, signature stuff I was using to basically strip it back to "my original" and the "polar bear" solution.

I will update the main code block to show.  And you are right, with all the extra stuff removed and the two solutions compared then I get around a 70% speed up not 100%.

This exercise has been great learning for me and the problem is solved.  Thank you Shawn, Zdim.